# Wrapping a high order component(HOC) around a React component in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm using the [JSX style](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react) of writing React and I'm trying to access the functionality of this [onClickOutside](https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside) wrapper to find out when the user clicks away. Here's the usage in its README:

```
// How to install: npm install react-onclickoutside --save
// load the High Order Component:
var onClickOutside = require('react-onclickoutside');

// create a new component, wrapped by this onclickoutside HOC:
var MyComponent = onClickOutside(React.createClass({
  ...,
  handleClickOutside: function(evt) {
    // ...handling code goes here...
  },
  ...
}));
```

I tried to access the "click outside" functionality it in this case (in JSX), but it didn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import OnClickOutside from 'react-onclickoutside';

export default class Menu extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <OnClickOutside>
                <ul>
                    <li>Test 1</li> 
                    <li>Test 2</li> 
                    <li>Test 3</li> 
                </ul>
            </OnClickOutside>
        );
    }


    handleClickOutside(event) {
        console.log('Clicked outside.');
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using ReactDOM to render your app?

Comment: Yup, like this:
http://i.imgur.com/LQ070Ss.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing a [Higher-Order Component](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775) (HOC) and a Container Component in this case.  A HOC takes a Component (in your case `Menu`) and then returns a Component (composed with the HOC functionality).  While a Container Component renders its children.

As the example shows, the `onOutsideClick` Component is a HOC.  This should work for your example:

```
import React from 'react';
import OnClickOutside from 'react-onclickoutside';

export class Menu extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }


    render() {

        return (      
                <ul>
                    <li>Test 1</li> 
                    <li>Test 2</li> 
                    <li>Test 3</li> 
                </ul>
        );
    }


    handleClickOutside(event) {
        console.log('Clicked outside.');
    }
}

export default OnOutsideClick(Menu);
```

Comment: It works! I'm still learning how to do this JSX thing. Thank you!